# declaring variable value as array and how to access the value

Tags: tcl

I am declaring my array with a predefined variable with a value. Now I want to access array value by using the predefined variable name, not by variable value using tcl.

**Example:**

```
set asd pll

set ${asd}(direct) input

puts ${$asd}(direct) # i am gettig error "can't read "$asd": no such variable"

puts $pll(direct) # "input" ( now i am able to access my array value)
```

I want to access my array value from asd variable only. Is there a way to get it using tcl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already found how to write to it. To read from it, use the single-argument form of `set` instead of the non-working embedded-`$`-form:

```
# set with a single argument does a read
puts [set ${asd}(direct)]
```

The other didn't work because `${…}` is a *syntactic* form that doesn't interpret the bit inside the braces at all (except to look for `::` and `(…)`, as those are part of variable names).

---

**However**, you should probably use `upvar 0` to make a variable alias instead:

```
set asd pll
upvar 0 $asd ary

# Now we can use simple access syntax
set ary(direct) input
puts $ary(direct)

# Show that it has worked for real...
parray pll
```

This works more nicely when you're in a procedure because then the alias only lasts until the procedure finishes. Otherwise, the only operation you can do on the alias without altering the underlying variable is to retarget the alias to point to a different variable. (When you do `upvar 1`, the same mechanism is used. It just looks the aliased variable up in a different stack frame.)